# Catch HTTP errors when using the Request module in Python3

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests

I'm using the code below which works well, however if I get an error 404 the code following the code block below it starts throwing errors and doesn't work due to the error 404, so I would like to catch the error 404 and if found don't process the following code just return as the code below is inside of a function.

```
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.request import urlopen

req = Request(
    url,
    data=None,
    headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
)

client = urlopen(req)
req_raw_data = client.read()
print(req_raw_data)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, see [Error handling in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll want to use a basic `try-except` block to handle errors.

`urllib` has the handy-dandy `urllib.error.HTTPError` to catch whatever errors you'll come across for you!

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


def make_request(url, token):
    req = Request(url)
    req.add_header('Authorization', f'Bearer {token}')
    
    try:
        response = urlopen(req)
        # Process the response data here
        # ...
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 404:
            print('Error: Page not found')
        else:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
```

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem I didn't use your code as a pure copy and paste but it helped me make some changes to my exising code which fixed my problem, I hadn't realise I needed to import something extra for the HTTPError stuff to work, I actually did try that prior to my post above but I was just getting more errors, anyway much appreciate everything is working great now.

Comment: Hahaha, sorry, ya I didn't include all your headers in there, did I---I just took something from a project I had open and edited it a bit.

Comment: Oh it's fine no problem, I knew some of what you posted except I couldn't get it to work as I was missing an import that I didn't know I needed. It's all good thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `try` and `except` block. Something like this would work:

```
try:
    client = urlopen(req)
    req_raw_data = client.read()
    print(req_raw_data)
except: # if you want to catch specific errors use add the error type/name here
    print('didnt work') # add your piece of code here
```

Comment: Ah thank you, yes I knew about the try and except, but when I did `except HTTPError` where you have `except:` that didn't work it just gave me more errors.

I will try just `except:` and see if that works for me or not.

Comment: if I use `except HTTPError:` I get this error `NameError: name 'HTTPError' is not defined. Did you mean: 'TabError'?`

Comment: @AeroMaxx for that you first need to do something like this: `from urllib.error import HTTPError`

Comment: Yeah someone else mentioned that, I wasn't aware I needed to do that however!